# jscrollpane works for only one table

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Documents/SmallTest/jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Documents/SmallTest/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/SmallTest/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Documents/SmallTest/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.horizontal-only
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table,th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function() 
{         
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $(this).build();
}); 

var map1 = { "iDate":"test_value1", "iName":"test_value2" , "iFile":"test value three 3 " }; 
var map2 = { "iDate":"nexttest_value1", "iName":"nexttest_value2", "iFile":"next test value three 3" }; 

var list = new Array( map1, map2 );
list[0] = map1;
list[1] = map2;

jQuery.fn.build = ( function() 
{
    jQuery.each( list, function( index, map ) {
        var trTag = $( "<tr></tr>" ).appendTo($( "#hpTable > tbody"));     
        jQuery.each( map, function( key, value ) 
        {             
            var tdTag = $( '<td/>' ).appendTo( trTag );             
            var divTag = $( "<div class='scroll-pane horizontal-only' id='container' style='vertical-align: top'/>" ).appendTo( tdTag );             
            $( "<p>" + value + "</p>" ).appendTo( divTag );
        });
    });
    $( '#hpTable' ).show();
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
<table id="popFields" width="10%">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>
        <select id="numberList">
            <option value="1" selected>one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><div id="firstDiv" class="scroll-pane horizontal-only"><p>this is a test for the scrollbar div tag. ljilkjlkjlkj lkjl ljfh gfyt gyjhy uyg  jhgj kjhg jhgu jfse dgf fdrh gfhtf hgf gfh td ghtffg ug fghgf.</p></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>

<table id="hpTable" cellpadding="0" width="30px">
<thead><tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th width="2%">File</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table></body></html>
```

Hello all, I'm back again and getting better with JQuery.  Here's a small example (shown above) of my issue.  I'm using this wonderful jScrollPane plugin, but for some reason I can't get two different tables to work...if I use it on one table it works fine.  However, when I have two tables, I can't get the scrollbars to show up.

I want to be able to allow each table the ability to have each cell that can have a scrollbar, if the text is too long for a cell, the cell will show the scrollbar.

I tried to play around with the size of the table and cells, but that seem to make no difference.  Using different div IDs didn't seem to have any impact either.

Thanks in advance for reviewing my post and any help is appreciated!  Happy Friday!

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, which table exactly is not showing the jScrollbar?

Comment: The top table - at first, but then as I tried to fix the top table, the bottom table doesn't work now...ugh. I'm using Firefox and both tables don't show the scrollbar. Thanks for reviewing my code.

Comment: Make sure to add enough content on that table to overflow the `td` so the jScrollbar can appear.

Comment: Still no luck, the table just grows wider and wider...I tried setting the width of the table and the cell, but nothing.

Comment: There's a typo on the `width` attribute of your second table, `<table id="hpTable" cellpadding="0" width="30px">` ...that `30px` should be just `30`.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything either.  I'm using Firefox 11.0.

Comment: ported your code to http://jsfiddle.net, its working fine with a few width tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/g6ST3/

Comment: It doesn't work in IE9 either.  Adding width of 30 to the cell didn't help either.  The cell just stretches the table wider.

Comment: dont have IE9 to test but i did test under IE7 and 8 and it worked fine so can't help you past that point but what i can tell you is that you have to make sure that you have a DOCTYPE declared on your document, i don't see one stated on your code above. So make sure you have something like this at the absolute top of your html page: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, good luck.